# nginx why get 403 when using the regular matching of location?

Tags: nginx

```
 location ~*  /engine-apps/exp/aaa {
      alias   /Users/easonmma/tencent/code/IDC-zhiwei/bpm-front-end/local-web-test/html/aaa;
      index  index.html;
  }
```

this config will get 403 when access /engine-apps/exp/aaa.

location /engine-apps/exp/aaa {
alias   /Users/easonmma/tencent/code/IDC-zhiwei/bpm-front-end/local-web-test/html/aaa;
index  index.html;
}
this config can access correctly.
why ,what is different?

if I use regular way to match location, I will get 403 always.

mac OS.
nginx version: nginx/1.25.1

Comment: See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias), but the simple answer is they are totally different. If you must use a regular expression, then you must also capture the remainder of the URL and add it to the alias expression.